# How to customize a legend in matlab plot window

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

As shown in the image below, the legend is too long for the plot window. what I want to do is:

**1-** To know how to split the legend over a second line?

**2-** To know how to shorten the red line in indicated in the legend. As you see, the legend contains a red line then (x1=......), I want to know whether there is any possibility to shorten that red line or to control its length.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities to control the content of the legend:

1. **Use of TeX commands**: MATLAB parses the legend entries (and titles, labels etc.) with TeX. You can use most TeX features and symbols. You find some details in the [MATLAB help pages](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend-properties.html), in the *Interpreter* section.
2. **sprintf**: The `sprintf` function works like all `printf` functions and outputs a string. It allows you to add control characters like `\n`, insert variables etc. Have a look at the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) for details.

In your case, you can use either of the following code snippets:

```
legend('x1 = x = ... \newline ...');
legend(sprintf('x1 = x = ... \n, ...'));
```

On your second question: I'm not aware of any possibility to change that line. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As for you second question - you can call legend with 2 output arguments:

```
[h,att] = legend('show')
```

And then use `att.XData` property to manipulate this line.

```
plot(sin(-pi:0.1:pi),'r')
[h,att] = legend('show')
att(2).XData(2) = 0.2;
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @user2121 if this answer helped you please follow the guidelines of the site and [upvote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer

Answer (score 0):

This thread is old, but I'm leaving an answer because I managed to find it.

The legend handle length can be set by passing `handlelength` as an argument. The default length is 2.0 in font-size units.

```
legend(loc='lower left',handlelength=1.0)
```