# Creating a legend in MATLAB that includes scatter plots and normal plots

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

I want my legend to include the line from the plot and the marker from the scatterplot. For example,

```
rest = importdata('test.xlsx');

x = test.data(:,1);
y = test.data(:,2);

xx = min(x):0.001:max(x); 
yy = interp1(x,y,xx,'cubic');

figure
s1 = scatter(x,y, 'filled', 'k');
hold on
p1 = plot(xx,yy, '--k');

legend(p1, 'x1');
```

This code creates the legend with only the dashes from the plot and not points from the scatterplot.  I would like the legend to have the both the point and the dashed line at the same label.  Something like "-.-"

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: See: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39952256/make-squared-in-legend-instead-of-lines-matlab) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788015/writing-2-variables-in-a-legend-with-2-different-plots) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686180/how-to-customize-a-legend-in-matlab-plot-window) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539552/matlab-how-to-set-color-of-legend-in-a-scatter-plot-where-each-data-point-gets), for some customizations of the figure legend

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Make a dummy plot with no data (`nan`) for the legend (also, as you can see here you can plot all the elements with one call to `plot`:

```
p = plot(nan,nan,'--ok', xx,yy,'--k', x,y,'ok');
set(p,{'MarkerFaceColor'},{'k'}); % fill the circles
legend('x1');
```

The result:

[image: dummy legend]

### Option 2

Insted of `legend(p1, 'x1');`, write this:

```
[~,ico] = legend(p1,'x1'); % create the legend, and get handels to it's parts
ico(3).Marker = 'o'; % set the marker to circle 
ico(3).MarkerFaceColor = 'k'; % set it's fill color to black
```

`ico` is:

```
  3×1 graphics array:

  Text    (x1)
  Line    (x1)
  Line    (x1)
```

The first element is the text 'x1' in the figure. The second element is the dashed line, and the third is the (not-exist) marker of p1. This third element is reserved for cases like `plot(xx,yy,'--ok');` where the legend include both marker and a line, but the line (**in the legend**) is represented with two points and the marker with only one, so we need different objects for them. Try to see what happens if you type `ico(2).Marker = 'o';` in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Legend in MATLAB is additional axes that contains the same primitive object like lines and text.
If you want to draw custom legend the simple way will be using primitive commands `line`, `text` and `patch` for rectangles with filling. Also you can add one more axes object as a container.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `p1` in the legend command you are telling MATLAB to only insert an item in the legend for the line corresponding to handle `p1` - which is what you are seeing.

In your example case you just want

```
>>legend({'label_for_scatter','label_for_plot'});
```